# In Ruby on Rails, how can I get radio button state, true or false, to put in a label?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

My form has two radio buttons, public and private:

```
 <div class='review-form'>
      <%= simple_form_for(@review) do |f| %>
  # input boxes for current_user to put text here

  #'public' radio button, checked by default, class is for css
  <%= f.radio_button :visible, "true" , :class => "share_button" %>

  #'private' radio button, class is for css
  <%= f.radio_button :visible, "false", :class => "keep_private_button" %>

  #user can cancel
  <%= link_to I18n.t('write_review.cancel_button'), landing_page, 
  :class => 'btn' %>

  #user can submit
  <%= f.button :submit, I18n.t('write_review.submit_button'), 
  :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

How can I determine if the radio button in each review is true or false, so I can use it after the review has been saved in my app?

For example, something like:

```
   <% if @review.radio_button.value = true %>
    <%= label_tag("This review is public") %>
     <% end %>

     <% if @review.radio_button.value = false %>
     <%= label_tag("This review is private") %>
     <% end %>
```

Comment: I'm not sure the question is clear... shouldn't you check the @review state for that? something like @review.is_private?

Comment: sorry, I never heard of 'is_private?' You mean I could simply do something like 'If @review.is_private? etc'? Wouldn't I have to define a method somewhere, defining what's private and what's not?

Comment: sorry, I meant visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is "elsewhere?"  Is this after the user has saved?  If so, then you should just be able to say:

```
if @review.visible?
```

or

```
if review.visible?
```

depending on the scope of your variable.

If, by "elsewhere," you mean on the same page, then you'll need some clever javascript.  You can use something like jQuery to help here, but essentially you'll just want a listener on those radio buttons that, on click, fires off to a javascript function that evaluates the radio buttons, then updates the text of a div on the page appropriately.  It's a very common pattern that I'll leave as an exercise for the alert reader, as, again, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "elsewhere" -- from your question, though, I'm guessing it's the former (after the user has saved).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Yes, elsewhere - after user has saved. Not sure @review.visible? would do the trick - wouldn't that need to be determined by the state of the radio button, if it's public or private?

Comment: Yes, but once you saved, you are saving the value of the radio button (either true or false) into the visible field of the review model.  Thus, you can simply interrogate @review.visible to get the value that was saved.  After you save, the radio button is meaningless.  Depending on how your database is set up, if visible is a boolean field, you'll be able to use review.visible?.  If it's a string field, then you'll want to check review.visible == "true".

Comment: Also, just to clarify, the only reason you would need to check the radio button is if you had not already saved the data into the model.  And, in that case, you'd want javascript.  Since the data is saved, though, you can check the model, as the value has already been determined (as public or private) via the previous save.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've put <%= @review.visible? %> into my review page. On my list of reviews, it all comes up as 'true', even though sometimes the radio button is set to false. But then when I edit the radio button, to true, or vice-versa, and then save it, <%= @review.visible? %> matches the radio button. But when I leave the page and come back to it, @review.visible is set to true again, while the radio button has been saved in the correct state. Any suggestions how to fix this? Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I would test this in tandem with checking your database, to ensure the value you expect (true/false) is actually reaching the database.  Also, make sure you aren't overriding the visible? method in your model, as that could impact things.  But the radio button coming up as still selected false is probably just your browser caching.  A refresh of the page will probably undo that.  In your database, visibile is boolean field, correct?

Comment: By my database, do you mean my model? - more specifically: models/review.rb? I searched for visible in my whole project (started by someone else, not me) and all I can find in all my models is in the review.rb file:   attr_accessible :comment, :name, :phone, :user_id, :category_ids,  :address, :lng, :lat, 
 :visible, :repost_from, :search_ids

Comment: I meant in your database -- after you hit save, ensure that select visible from reviews where id = {id} is set to what you expect.  Rails will know what to do with the field based on the data definition, which is why it's hard to tell from within the model.  Checking the DB will tell the true story (you can also get the definition from db/schema.rb).  I'm assuming it's a boolean, but just double-checking.

Comment: Cheers, you've been more than helpful!

Comment: And yes, in schema.rb I can see t.boolean  "visible",                                    :default => true...so it is indeed a boolean.

Comment: No problem, let me know how things end up, but I would definitely start by ensuring the changes are making it to the database.  Since your schema is set up to default to true (instead of false), it could be the case that things are never really getting saved as false.  Also, noting that you're using simple_form, it may be easier to rig your form to use a checkbox instead of radio button -- will make simple_form happier, and then you can just do f.input instead of f.radio_button.  You'd need to override the label, though.  But, you'd know the saving aspect would go more smoothly.  Good luck!

Comment: In fact, review.visible? did exactly what I wanted - saving it to database permanently, whereas @review.visible? just did it until page was refreshed. Any idea of the logic behind this? Edited your answer to mention review.visible? and accepted it.

Comment: In your controller, you probably have a line like review = Review.find params[:id] instead of @review = Review.find params[:id]. That could potentially cause that.  It's fine in that context, since you'll be redirecting after the save.  I'll accept your edit, basically however your review is declared initially is how it should be saved.